Obtain elastic_strain_principal_1 from PyAnsys
Trying to obtain some data from a simulation saved in a rst file.
Initially we have:
from ansys.dpf import core as dpf
model = dpf.Model(r'.\file.rst')

We want to get elastic_strain_principal_1. We create an operator instance to perform it:
op = dpf.operators.result.elastic_strain_principal_1()

To fill the parameters of this instance we connect it to the model:
op.inputs.data_sources.connect(model.metadata.data_sources)

Despite this is made by default, we are going to ensure that we get principal strain first component in the last time step:
time_scoping = model.metadata.time_freq_support.time_frequencies.data[-1]
op.inputs.time_scoping.connect(float(time_scoping))

Then we create a filds container with the output and get the data:
result_fields_container = op.outputs.fields_container()
field = result_fields_container[0] #only time considered so [0]
field_data = field.data

As far as I know, we obtain the elastic strain principal on all the available nodes for the last time step, but this is not matching the results from Ansys Desktop App by far, if I take the maximum in field.data and the maximum principal strain 1 (that in this particular case always happens at the end of the simulation) in Ansys Deskot App there is a diference of 1.5 units.
I am having trouble understanding how PyAnsys works and why values are not matching.
Also I am doing the same operation for stress_principal_1 with the analogous code structure, in this case the values are correct, both PyAnsys and Ansys Desktop App return identical values, this leads to more confusion.

Are you sure you are comparing nodal averaged results? I made a simple test model and I have 1-to-1 (for min, max, average values) match between DPF and Mechanical between elastic_strain_principal_1 and Maximum Principal Elastic Strain.

@Tzane Thanks for your comment, I "solved" the issue using PyDPF-Post. Anyway I asked Ansys team about one of this problems, actually there was a issue/bug in Pyansys code. Thanks for your time!

Do you mind posting your solution here?

Maybe I can post something

(@Tzane) Despite I can't post the full code, I can sketch it. Just use the same approach as before but with from ansys.dpf import post. Assume we have the .rst file from ansys in the following local path: file = folder + 'file.rst', then just instantiate our simulation:
simulation = post.StaticMechanicalSimulation(file)
times = simulation.time_freq_support.time_frequencies.data

Once we have both, we can iterate over each time-step if needed or retrieve just from a specific time-step:
for step in times:
 for step in times:
    displacement = simulation.displacement(times=step)
    strain = imulation.elastic_strain_principal_nodal(times=step)
    stress = simulation.stress_principal_nodal(times=step)

This functions have other arguments such as components= where you can select axis, or named_selections= where you can choose the "body/selection".
